# How can I make a program that prints Numbers formed by 3 digits or more?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I stumbled across an exercise that asked me the following:

> Create a program that shows you the numbers formed by 3 digits and prints the biggest as well as the smallest.
>
> Example:
>
> N=472

So the outputs will be:

```
472, 427,742, 724, 274, 247.
The biggest number is 742 and the smallest is 247.
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: What should the outputs be for N=474?

Comment: the outputs for 474 will be 474 447 744 the biggest is 744 and the smallest is 447

Comment: well i know that we need an N which is in this case an input by the user and then from here i think i have to compare between the 3 digits and i guess they should be treated as stings right ?, after this i have no idea what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `permutations` from `itertools` module

```
from itertools import permutations

N = 472
l = [int(''.join(c)) for c in permutations(sorted(str(N)))]

print(*l, sep=', ')
print(f'The biggest number is {l[-1]} and the smallest is {l[0]}.')
```

Output:

```
247, 274, 427, 472, 724, 742
The biggest number is 742 and the smallest is 247.
```

Because you sort digits by ascending order and the implementation of `permutations`, the first element of the list is the smallest number and the last element is the biggest.

**Update**

```
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
    
    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

```
>>> print(l)
[247, 274, 427, 472, 724, 742]

>>> print(*l)
247 274 427 472 724 742

>>> print(*l, sep=',')
247, 274, 427, 472, 724, 742
```

Comment: this is genius! thank you so much brother, this is what i was lookin for <3

Comment: can u explain that: sep=', '

Comment: @MohammedAbbassi print by default places a space (" ") between elements. You can replace this using the sep argument (default sep value is " ").

Comment: I updated my answer with the documentation of print and a step-by-step transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for min and max value:

```
N = 472
sorted_digits = sorted(str(N))
number = "".join(sorted_digits)
print(f"The biggest number is {number[::-1]} and the smallest is {number}.")
```

EDIT: You can try to use permutations from module itertools for get all numbers:

```
from itertools import permutations

N = 472
all_permutations = list(map(lambda t: "".join(t), permutations(str(N), len(str(N)))))
print(*all_permutations)
```

Comment: thanks it actually works super well, but it looks so clean and professional, is there an easy way to sort them?

Comment: @MohammedAbbassi, In this case, I am sorting using basic python mechanisms. Python sorts strings in a lexicographic sense. For this reason, sorted("472") == ["2", "4", "7"]. It remains only to join the list of strings into a string using the python join method.

Answer (score -1):

```
n=int(input("-Enter Number Of Numbers :"))
x=int(input("-Enter Number :"))
g=x
s=x
for i in range(n-1) :
    x=int(input("-Enter Number :"))
    if x>g :
        g=x
    elif x<s :
        s=x
print("The Greatest Number :",g)
print("The Smaller Number :",s)
```

Comment: This may be solving *some* problem, but not the one posed in this question.

Comment: the code works perfectly fine but it's not what i asked for, thank you tho i really appreciate it dude